# Is there force without pressure?

Tags: forces, pressure

I know that when an object has been applied force to, this is called pressure, so if I apply some kind of force to a chair like push it forward or pull it forward that would be pressure, my question is that can there be force without pressure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your definition of pressure. The usual one in physics, [given by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure), is the amount of force acting per unit area, perpendicular to the surface.

Whenever you apply a force to something, if the force is distributed on the surface (meaning that the force you are applying can be described by many small forces perpendicular to the surface), you can define a pressure. 
Concretely, when you push a chair with your finger, the pressure will be something close to the total force you apply to the chair divided by the surface of your finger.

Many forces can't be described with the notion of pressure. For example, the weight is a force which is distributed on the volume of an object so you won't be able to understand this force with pressure.

Comment: That's so confusing... Can you be more simply explaining pressure? sorry. I find it hard to understand

Comment: Ok let me try to be less technical. 

I think that when you say pressure, you don't think about the physical definition of pressure. See wikipedia for this (link in previous answer).

Then, take a ball in your hand and let it fall. A force is applied on the ball that makes it fall. Is it a pressure ? I don't think so.

Comment: So when I pull a chair this is force. When I sit on chair this is pressure? correct?

Comment: Somehow you are right, but it's not physically correct ;-). I suggest you to dig into what pressure is, the physical meaning and you will understand my concerns.

Comment: So when the force of gravity is applied to an object(lets say ball)  in the air it pushes it downwards, we consider the object as the surface and gravity as the force. So isn't this an overall pressure? then why can't we call it pressure?

Comment: The force is not on the surface of the object but on the volume of the object. Let's take another example which will be more explicit : take a ball with an electric charge +1 and another with an electric charge -1. There will be a force between the 2 balls right ? Then you can change the surface of the balls in anyway you want, the force will be the same between the 2 balls. It means the force has nothing to do with the surface, so with the concept of pressure.

Comment: Sorry I am slow at understanding. Isn't volume the inside of the ball so gravity is acting on the inside of the ball not against the ball correct?

Comment: I can't explain much more right now. Anyway, don't bother to much with this. What is important is the concept of force. Some forces can be described as pressures but only few of them (if they are distributed on a surface). That 's it :)

Comment: Ok I will ask a different question regarding this topic. :P

Comment: Pressure relates to force in the same way density relates to mass. You have some amount of force and you can do a lot with that information, but sometimes you want to know how much force per unit if area. Similarly, if someone tells you they have a certain amount of some material (mass) it tells you a lot, but if you want to know whether it will fit into your car you will need to know it’s it’s volume (which tells you it’s density mass/Volume).